# TeamCity v7 - Receive notification if SVN Externals path is invalid

Tags: svn, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

How can I configure TeamCity so that I receive a notification (email or tray) if an SVN Externals path is invalid?

The situation was that a build was not starting because the VCS root step failed with the following error:

```
Error collecting changes for VCS repository 'XYZ trunk'
Checkout rule: 
Path is invalid: 
'https://SvnServer:8443/svn/DotNet/Code/Modules/ExternalABC/Tags/2.4.0.0/2.4.0.39711/bin'@39825
```

An External declared on "XYZ trunk" pointed to an invalid path. This was committed, and **no** notifications were raised. The TeamCity Quick View shows a green light against the project, since the last actual *build* succeeded.

As things stand, the build is broken in that a checkout of the XYZ Trunk does not compile (missing external dll), but no notifications were sent and no error icons are shown in the tray.

This seems wrong - what have I not done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a notification rule for failure notifications set up already.  If so, you just need to put a check in "The build fails to start" for the notification rule in question.

If you would do it under "Administration->Groups" under the group you want to set up the notifications for.  If you want to notify "All users" for all builds that failed with their changes you can set up a rule that has "The build fails", "Ignore failures not caused by my changes" and "The build starts" all checked.

Be warned though this can lead to extra "false positive" notifications when there are problems with the source control server.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that and post back.